# How does hello.js avoid storing the client_secret?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I'm currently on a mission to figure out how to adequately utilize an OAuth 2.0 provider strictly from client-side javascript and have concerns about exposing the application's `client_secret`.  Which is essentially the "password" of the OAuth client.

How does [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js) avoid the `client_secret` all together?

Do these providers rely on the referrer and application domain to validate (identify) client requests?

Comment: you just need to use your client_id, not the secret. providers _may_ check the referrer, but it's not needed because they must re-direct to page on a site you control anyway. that landing page gets info from the 3rd party using location.hash, which doesn't go over http. if the landing page info matched what the client was expecting, the request is said to be authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HelloJS uses the Implicit Flow by default - @dandavis describes in his comment. If the service does not support the Implicit Grant Flow, perhaps it supports the OAuth2 Authentication Code/ Explicit Grant or OAuth1 Authentication flow - all of the above require a hidden secret key to be used in processing requests - HelloJS diverts the request via an OAuth Proxy (see http://adodson.com/hello.js/#oauth-proxy)  the proxy's job is to complete the handshake and return an access_token.

Comment: If I use an OAuth Proxy (either  https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/ or my own), and store the secret key by accessing the Proxy's webpage, signed in with my own credentials, how does HelloJS access that information for a user not signed in with my credentials? And if HelloJS can access that information without my credentials, then why isn't it available to everyone, thus no longer secret?